# How to update the Empty String in .csv for BULK API , if for that particular Field already exist value in UI?

Tags: bulk-api

I already tried passing value as #N/A for that particular column but instead it is taking it as String in UI
Refered this Document (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_prepare_csv.htm?search_text=null)

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Are you saying , in UI there is Field  lets call it 'MyString' which has some value, and you want to update that field value to null. For that you are preparing the .csv for bulk update.  Also,  What is the data type of the Field in UI?

Comment: yes, in UI there is Field lets call it 'MyString' which has some value, and I want to update that field value to null and i am preparing the .csv for bulk update and data type is text for the filed 'MyString'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Data Loader to Update a field in Salesforce with Null Values, then first you need to set the  'Insert Null Values' to true

1. Open Data Loader
2. Click Settings
3. Select Insert Null Values
4. Click OK

[image]

This article will exactly explain what to do and how

[Change record values to blank or null with Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000327368&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: thanks GroundToCloud , but i am not using dataloader or any other tools ,think of just i am passing it through postman